# Ajax отправка одинаковых форм только с разными <input type=hidden value="">

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form, input

```js
$(".send_callback").submit(function() { //Change
  var th = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../php/callback_top.php", //Change
    data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    alert('Спасибо за заявку! \nНаши менеджеры свяжутся с вами в ближайшее время.');
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Done Functions
      th.trigger("reset");
    }, 500);
  });
  return false;
});

$(".send_prazdnik_bron").submit(function() { //Change
  var th = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../php/send_prazdnik_bron.php", //Change
    data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    alert('Спасибо за заявку! \nНаши менеджеры свяжутся с вами в ближайшее время.');
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Done Functions
      th.trigger("reset");
    }, 500);
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="price_message send_callback" action="" method="post">
  <h5>Оставьте заявку</h5>
  <p>Наш менеджер свяжется с Вами для уточнения деталей заказа</p>
  <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
  <input type="tel" required="" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="phone">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control control-checkbox">
            Нажимая на кнопку, Вы принимаете условия <br> <a class="politica" href="politica.html" target="_blank">политики конфиденциальности</a> и даете свое<br> согласие на обработку персональных данных<br> на условиях и для целей, указанных в нём
            <input type="checkbox" required=""/>
            <div class="control_indicator"></div>
          </label>
  </div>
  <button class="price_btn" type="submit">Заказать звонок</button>
</form>




<form class="price_message send_prazdnik_bron" action="" method="post">
  <h5>Оставьте заявку</h5>
  <p>Наш менеджер свяжется с Вами для уточнения деталей заказа</p>
  <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
  <input type="tel" required="" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="phone">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control control-checkbox">
            Нажимая на кнопку, Вы принимаете условия <br> <a class="politica" href="politica.html" target="_blank">политики конфиденциальности</a> и даете свое<br> согласие на обработку персональных данных<br> на условиях и для целей, указанных в нём
            <input type="checkbox" required=""/>
            <div class="control_indicator"></div>
          </label>
  </div>
  <button class="price_btn" type="submit">Забронировать праздник</button>
</form>
```

А вот тут php (они идентичные, только в описании написано с какой формы пришла заявка)

```
<?php

$recepient = "mail@mail.ru";
$sitename = "Сайт.рф";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$message = "Форма с кнопки (Заказать звонок (сверху)) \nИмя: $name \nТелефон: $phone";

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");

<?php

$recepient = "mail@mail.ru";
$sitename = "Сайт.рф";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$message = "Форма с кнопки (Забронировать праздник) \nИмя: $name \nТелефон: $phone";

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

Comment: А какой вопрос, или Вы просто хвастаетесь?

Comment: Проблема в том, что если надо например 30 таких форм, то придётся код дублировать. Знаю, что можно отличать формы с помощью скрытых полей <input type="hidden">, но как это сделать - ума не приложу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляешь в каждую форму input hidden с разными value и единым name

```
<input type=hidden name="type" value="callback" >
<input type=hidden name="type" value="prazdnik_bron">
```

итд.

Вешаешь обработчик событий на единый класс (.price_message) форм и отправляешь данные c формы на единый URL (к примеру send.php)

```
$(".price_message").submit(function() { 
  var th = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../php/send.php", //
    data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    alert('Спасибо за заявку! \nНаши менеджеры свяжутся с вами в ближайшее 
время.');
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Done Functions
      th.trigger("reset");
    }, 500);
  });
  return false;
});
```

В send.php делаешь условия:

```
if (trim($_POST["type"]) = "callback")
{
    //Отправляем email менеджеру 1
}
else if (trim($_POST["type"]) = "prazdnik_bron")
{
    //Отправляем email менеджеру 2
}
```

Количество форм с классом .price_message можно добавлять до бесконечности.
Для каждой формы, главное задавать уникальное значение input hidden и задавать для него нужное условие в send.php

Answer (score 0):

В самой форме:

```
<form class="price_message ..." method="post" data-target="somewhere.php">
```

В коде:

```
$(".price_message").submit(function() { 
  var th = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: th.data('target'), // здесь берем из тега data-target
    data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
     // ...
  });
  return false;
});
```

Ещё лучше будет брать данные из свойства `action` формы и доработать обработчики чтобы они работали без AJAX. В этом случае формы будут работать и без JS.